# Corrected P-value returned as NaN

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have attempted to run a FDR correction on an array of p-values using both statsmodels.stats.multitest's multipletests(method='fdr_bh') and fdrcorrection. In both instances I receive an array of NaN's as the corrected p-values. I do not understand why the corrected p-value is returning as NaN. Could someone please help explain?

Comment: Please add a code sample so we can reproduce your issue [mcve].

Comment: You can also ask your question on Cross-Validated site instead of SO, which is only about statistics

Answer (score 2):

Check for NaNs in your p-value array. using multipletests on an array with any NaNs will return all NaNs, as you describe.